# Unable to access godaddy hosting (and even godaddy.com) from my network

Tags: networking, security, web-server, hosting, godaddy

After trying to communicate with both my ISP and Godaddy support I decided to post my issue over here.

Issue: Getting Error "You don't have permission to access "http://www.godaddy.com/" on this server." while trying to access godaddy.com.

And while Trying to access any Godaddy hosted site of mine getting this error "This site can’t be reached".

My Public IP : 182.73.28.46 (static)

Already checked for blacklisted cases and got it removed from a couple of websites (including http://www.abuseat.org/lookup.cgi, www.spamhaus.org) but still no luck.

As per godaddy they can't and doesn't blacklist any IP and same is the case with my ISP. Anyone ever faced similar issue or know how to fix it up ?

### Traceroute

traceroute to godaddy.com (104.238.65.160), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets

1. 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  1.830 ms  1.170 ms  0.813 ms
2. 182.73.28.45 (182.73.28.45)  38.196 ms  26.392 ms  25.614 ms
3. 182.79.245.225 (182.79.245.225)  177.276 ms
   182.79.245.161 (182.79.245.161)  185.897 ms
   182.79.245.225 (182.79.245.225)  155.043 ms
4. 213.242.116.165 (213.242.116.165)  382.945 ms  300.459 ms
   213.242.116.157 (213.242.116.157)  300.659 ms
5. '* * *'
6. the-go-dadd.bear1.phoenix1.level3.net (4.16.142.186)  340.254 ms  353.208 ms  468.316 ms
7. ip-184-168-0-117.ip.secureserver.net (184.168.0.117)  361.239 ms  308.855 ms  306.429 ms
8. ip-184-168-0-117.ip.secureserver.net (184.168.0.117)  426.291 ms
   ip-184-168-0-113.ip.secureserver.net (184.168.0.113)  303.738 ms  390.144 ms

   9. '* * *'
   10. '* * *'
   11. '* * *'
   12. '* * *'
   13. '* * *'
   14. '* * *'

Comment: Please share your traceroute output.

Comment: Added traceroute @AlexanderT

Comment: please show traceroute to IP where your site is located.